# jQuery $.post not giving any result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .post

I know this question has already been asked previously. However, I am unable to find a fix to my problem. I am trying to use $.post to search a MySQL databse, just to test the code I have set the customer_lookup.php to echo 'Hello'. For some reason, this code isn't working, I have checked this across many tutorials and docs and can't find any problems, but for some reason I get no result.

```
$('input#customer_search_submit').on('click', function() {

    var customer_name = $('input#customer_name').val();

    $.post('/ajax/customer_lookup.php', {customer_name: customer_name}, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    })

});
```

If I remove the $.post and just put alert(customer_name); this outputs the form data in a alert, as expected, so I am sure that the problem is with the $.post

I appreciate any help/guidance.

Thanks

Comment: That isn't even valid JavaScript and will result in a Syntax Error. Look at the error console. (Assuming that the real code doesn't have that error, it could be that the server returns a non-success response in which case the "success" callback will not be called. Check with the browsers Network Monitor.)

Comment: By the way, if you are using Google Chrome, you may press CTRL+SHIFT+J  to open up javascript console which will show you what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Cancel the click event!

```
$('input#customer_search_submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! this finally worked, in many examples of code like mine other people don't seem to be using/need to use .preventDefault(), could you explain why? Thanks again

Comment: Because you are using a submit button which is posting back the form. If you used a regular button it would not submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript looks ok. You should check if you have specified correct url. Try adding an [error handler](http://api.jquery.com/error/) to your code like the following:

```
$('input#customer_search_submit').on('click', function() {
    var customer_name = $('input#customer_name').val();
    $.post('/ajax/customer_lookup.php', {customer_name: customer_name}, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }).error(function(){alert(arguments[1]+" "+ arguments[2]);});
});
```

Obviously, you need to learn how to work with a console. Check: Developer Tools (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+J) for Chrome, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/faq/#Is_there_some_basic_description_of_how_Firebug_works) for Firefox, Developer Tools (F12) for IE)